# webscraping behind a login with selenium. Getting element errors

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape a website behind a login form.
here are the problematic snippets.

```py
import csv
import re

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('URL')

username = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#email_address')
password = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#password')

username_input.send_keys('EMAIL')
password_input.send_keys('PASS')

login_button = driver.find_element(By.NAME,'login')
login_button.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

toggle_button = driver.find_element(By.ID,'toggle_pp2_app_list')

if not toggle_button.is_selected():
  toggle_button.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

link = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,'4,766')
link.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

link = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'appId')
link.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(3)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

links = soup.find_all('a')
next_page_link = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,'Next')
next_page_link.click()

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

clean_links = [re.sub(r'\s+', '', link.text.strip()) for link in links]
with open('links.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
  writer = csv.writer(f)
  writer.writerow(['Link'])
  writer.writerows([[link] for link in clean_links])
driver.quit()
```

That's my whole code with personal info removed.
my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test4.py", line 8, in <module>
email_address = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#email_address')
NameError: name 'By' is not defined
```

I've tried changing out the `find_element(By.CSS_Selector with (By.NAME, By.LINK_TEXT`

I don't know what it's getting caught up on.

Comment: What is `By` here?

Comment: Your code? Copy pasted code? `By` seems to be some object with fields that hold the things you are trying to look for ... your code does not show any construction or provision of `By` - and your error exactly tells you that `By` is not known ...... not sure how SO is able to help you.

Comment: If anyone is at all familiar with developing with selenium, then it is a pretty fair assumption that `By` here is referring to `selenium.webdriver.common.by.By`. Not sure why SO wouldn't be able to pick up on that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Selenium's `By`, you need to import it:

Add this to the top of your code before you try using `By`

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

As a general point: any term/variable that is used has to either be imported or defined somewhere in your code, unless it is a keyword of some kind or a built-in.

Since `By` is not a built-in method of Python and the code did not define it, that suggests we likely needed to import it from somewhere.